# Windows Application or web application for this purpose

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have about 5000 csv file and I want to insert them in a sql server 2008 database.

I don't whether windows application or web application is better.

each csv file is simple a one row with 36 column that will be inserted in an **one** table in the database.

thanks for your help.

#### Update 1

This application will be used on a computer that can connect to the database, it is used by the admin just once, in order words, there are people who responsible to write these csv files, then all the files, come to me and I have to insert them in the database

#### Update 2

Thanks for the user who are trying to help me.

You gave me these options:

1. bcp
2. SqlBulkCopy
3. Windows service

what is the best please? I told you all the requirements, which are very simple.

Comment: To answer this you need to tell us how you intent your users to use that? Will they use different os-es, will they use mobile devices, will they use automatic transfers, ...?

Comment: @Jester I update the question for you

Comment: You may just use the `bcp` utility which ships with SQL Server (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx).

Comment: @AlexKiselev I need to have a very small interaction, for example, if any wrong happens, I need to tell that this file has not being written, you got me please?

Comment: @AgnieszkaPolec If you have to do this periodically, you can rather create a windows service for it. This service can pick up the XML from a predefined location and process it. You can write the success/error into the logs from the service

Comment: @Virus that sounds a good solution, is that applicable to do it with `sqlBulkCopy` ?

Comment: @AgnieszkaPolec `bcp` is able to report errors and even store the failed records into a separate file. If working with command line is OK, `bcp` should fit your task perfectly.

Comment: @AgnieszkaPolec Yes we can create the service in C# and use sqlBulkCopy into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends how you want to use it - if you want to deploy to lots of people so they can upload a file and process it into a database, make it web.

If on the other hand, you only have a couple of users which you can easily deploy an app to, there is a lot less infrastructure required to write it as an app.

Sounds to me, you want to automate the mass loading of lots of files, so windows app is jumping out at me.

All depends on what the overall requirements are.

Based on your edit, write a win app that uses a folder enumeration, reads the records and passes to a [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx) object.

Comment: I am trying to find example for this `sqlBulkCopy` +1 anyway

Comment: There is one on the link I provided if you scroll down to the end.

Comment: some other user suggested to use a windows service and this service can read the csv files from their locations and insert them with error/success log, do you think that this can be done with you `SqlBulkCopy` please?

Comment: absolutely - a service is a windows app with no user interface. You will need to incorporate a logging mechanism so you get some outputs for your error, be that to file or event viewer. You will also need something to trigger import - a FileSystemWatcher or Timer.

Comment: the example you provided is using the sqlbuilkcopy to insert data from a table to another table, could you tell me where can I find an example to insert a csv file to a table using sql bulk copy? or any similar example that can help me. many thanks

Comment: You just need to read your CSV, row by row into a DataTable. Create a DataTable to match your target table schema (can't help you with that) - then use a StreamReader to take each line from your source file into a string and then .Split() on your seperator value. That will give you an array of strings you can insert to the datatable

Answer (score 1):

based on your comment I would take an aproach like that:

**Easy to use gui solution:**
 1. Make a website for people that are making the csv's

1. That website would preform and check's that are necesery and display any errors. Error checking is done by the Web service (more future proven imo).
2. Create a webservice importing the file to database and sending you an email. That way you don't have any work with putting the data into the database
3. Implement an aproveal mechanism so you need to aprove the new inputs to the database if needed

**Easy to implement solution:**

1. Create an application (Console/WinForm/Web) that uses the bcp tool to import the data and handles errors

Comment: +1 for your efforts, I am still evaluating the options. many thanks